# Do we always have to close the stream?

Tags: java

Have a FileInputStream, I am wondering whether I need to close it or not? If yes, if I pass this stream object to the other method, can I close in that sub method?

Comment: yes, closing a stream is good habit after using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can close the stream in the method where you passed it.

But beware. If you use the same stream after the method call it will remain closed.

The best practice is to close the stream after you've done all you wanted with it.

Answer (score 2):

YES - If you are sure that nothing more will be written to the stream.

NO - e.g. using outputStream in Servlet - you get this stream, write to them but you don't close it. This is because something later can have access to the same stream. The main rule is: Always close streams which you open by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Yes you you should close it and you can close it if you pass it into a submethod. If you pass it into a Reader though, if you call close on the Reader it will also close the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can close the stream anywhere you want. But you should close the stream where you opened it for better readability. You can still process the stream in an other method:

```
 try {
     InputStream stream = //open the stream;
     PerformActionOnStream(s);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     //handle error
 } finally {
    stream.close();
 }
```

There is no reason to close the stream in `PerformActionOnStream()`. Just return when you are done.

In `java 7` is better to simply

```
try(InputStream stream = new MyStream()) {
    // code
} catch (Exception e) {
    //
}
```

Comment: How about the asynchronous case, I need to return immediately from PerformActionOnStream?

Comment: Interesting question. In this case it would depend on what you want to achieve. If you want to read the stream using another thread, I would suggest that the thread opens the file. In cases where that is not possilbe, you should write a comment, that you transfer ownership to the thread.

Comment: altho you can't define the InputStream in the try block, as it won't be available then scope-wise in the finally.

Comment: I'm working on an input stream and when I put the close method inside of the finally block I receive an error that you need to handle the IOException for the close method (which means another try/catch block inside of finally).  Is there a better way or best practice for handling this?  Would it be better to add a IOExeption to the method signature and let the caller deal with it?

Comment: It depends how you want to handle the error.

If you can handle an exception locally, do that. Most of them are exspectable exceptions, i.e. a file can not be read. If you can not handle them locally, pass it up the call stack by rethtrowing it.

When rethrowing an exception, you might wrap it into another exception. If you wrap it into a subclass of `RuntimeException`, you do not have to add an explicit throws declartion to each method call up the call stack to the final error handling. But think twice. By not using a throws clause, other developers can not exspect the exception.

Comment: For the particular case of `stream.close()` see: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/10/java-how-not-to-make-mess-of-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

You should always close a stream in order to free open resources on your OS. Opening a stream always returns an identifier which you can use to close it wherever you are in your code (as long as the identifier is valid), whether their from another method or class.